# Combine 2 complex mysql queries into one

Tags: mysql, if-statement

First off here's what my database looks like:

**Current** -- table

```
ID - Unique identifier for device (Int)  
Location -Unique identifier for name of area (VarChar)  
Status - The current status of the device (VarChar )  
Time - DateTime of when the last connection was made to the device (DateTime)
```

**Historical** - table

```
CID (Sorta unused, just as an AI field to store multiple old bits of data uniquely) (Int)  
ID - Unique identifier for device (Int)  
Location --Unique identifier for name of area (VarChar)  
Status - The current status of the device (VarChar )  
Time -- DateTime of when the last connection was made to the device (DateTime)
```

So that's how the database looks now my queries look like this....

**Query 1**

```
SELECT c.*, 
   if(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), c.TIME)) >=1, 1, 0) as LatestOlderThanAnHour,
   min(h.time) as EarliestTime, 
   (abs(timestampdiff(HOUR,NOW(),min(TIME)))/count(*)*100) as percentage
FROM Current c
JOIN Historical h on c.ID = h.ID
WHERE c.Location like "MyLocation"
group by c.ID
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT MAX(h.TIME) AS LastDown
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE h.STATUS IN ('On-Login-Screen','IE-Window-Missing')
```

The end goal is to add a "Last Down" column for each ID returned by this query.  I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: `max(case when h.status in ('On-Login-Screen','IE-Window-Missing') then h.time end)`

Comment: ^^ Make that into an answer so I can accept it, and thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
max(case when h.status in ('On-Login-Screen','IE-Window-Missing') then h.time end)
```

Or I guess you could also write it

```
max(if(h.status in ('On-Login-Screen','IE-Window-Missing'), h.time, NULL))
```